# The django-geoposition map widget is not showing up in the django admin on my production server, but it is working perfectly fine on my test server

Tags: django, django-admin, django-geoposition

The django geoposition widget shows up in admin when I am testing everything on my laptop with the django test server. However, when I put everything onto my production server, there is no map showing up and no labels showing up for the latitude and longitude. Both setups are using django == 2.1.7 and geoposition == 0.3.0. The production server is being served with nginx and gunicorn.

I opened the browser inspection window and it turned out that the geoposition.js is being served by django before jQuery is being called. So I tried calling jQuery directly in the geoposition.js file, but there is still no widget. I then revert everything back to it's original stage and I am now including js = (setting.STATIC_URL + 'geoposition/geoposition.js") in a media class in admin.py. This is causing two maps to appear in my test server, but still no map in my production server. I added an if statement so that it doesn't run if jQuery is not loaded, so no jQuery errors on the first geoposition.js being served. I added some console.log() statements to the file so I can see where it is at and it is getting into the main function fine, but not getting into the $('.geopostion-widget').each(function() ...

When I look at the html, the map and latitude and longitude values are wrapped in a div of class = "geoposition-widget", but that there is no such div from my production server which makes sense as to why the '.geopostion-widget' function is not doing anything. It seems to be putting in that div automatically on my test server, which it is supposed to do, but not on my production server.

Any clue as to why this is happening? Do I just need to create a custom form for the admin on my production server and wrap the field in a div with class = '.geopostion-widget'? This just seems kind of janky since it is working fine on my test server. Or does it have something to do with the way it's being served with gunicorn and nginx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer on github here - https://github.com/philippbosch/django-geoposition/issues/83.

imdario's answer at the bottom solved it. Upgraded geoposition package to imdario's geoposition pakcage with 'pip install django-geoposition-2' and voila - it works.